# javascript add missing keys in an object inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have the following array of objects.

```
{
    "students": {
        "fees": {
            "others": [
                {
                    "Student Name": "Ashy",
                    "Term1": "$1,000.00",
                    "Term2": "$1,000.00",
                    "Total": "$2,000.00",
                },
                {
                    "Student Name": "Test",
                    "Term1": "$1,000.00",
                    "Total": "$1,000.00",
                }
            ],
        }
    }
}
```

Here, second object does not have the key `Term2`. I want to have same keys in both the objects inside array. The output should be like below:

```
{
    "students": {
        "fees": {
            "others": [
                {
                    "Student Name": "Ashy",
                    "Term1": "$1,000.00",
                    "Term2": "$1,000.00",
                    "Total": "$2,000.00",
                },
                {
                    "Student Name": "Test",
                    "Term1": "$1,000.00",
                    "Term2": "",
                    "Total": "$1,000.00",
                }
            ],
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone please let me know how i can achieve this in javascript ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need all the elements to have the same set of keys - or just use one of the element as a 'template' one?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? What object defines the keys? Or can there be missing keys in both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary of keys to check against. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array of objects, and then use that dictionary to decide if a new property needs to be added to the object.

```js
const data = {
  "students": {
    "fees": {
      "others": [{
          "Student Name": "Ashy",
          "Term1": "$1,000.00",
          "Term2": "$1,000.00",
          "Total": "$2,000.00",
        },
        {
          "Student Name": "Test",
          "Term1": "$1,000.00",
          "Total": "$1,000.00",
        }
      ],
    }
  }
}

const dict = ['Student Name', 'Term1', 'Term2', 'Total'];

const out = data.students.fees.others.map(obj => {
  
  // Grab the object keys
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);

  // Iterate over the dictionary and if a
  // key is missing add it to the object
  for (let key of dict) {
    if (!keys.includes(key)) obj[key] = '';
  }

  return obj;

});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 3):

First findout the `all keys` to have in object.
Then, Use `map` to build new array and fill the missing keys with empty values.

```js
const data = {
  "students": {
    "fees": {
      "others": [{
          "Student Name": "Ashy",
          "Term1": "$1,000.00",
          "Term2": "$1,000.00",
          "Total": "$2,000.00",
        },
        {
          "Student Name": "Test",
          "Term1": "$1,000.00",
          "Total": "$1,000.00",
        }
      ],
    }
  }
}

const { students: { fees: { others } } } = data;

const keys = others.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => (Object.keys(curr).forEach((key) => acc.add(key)), acc),
  new Set()
);

const output = others.map((item) =>
  [...keys].reduce((acc, key) => ((acc[key] = item[key] ?? ""), acc), {})
);

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i create a list of all keys of all object keys within others array. And overwrite the original others array with a new one creates based on the list of keys.

```js
const data = {
    "students": {
        "fees": {
            "others": [
                {
                    "Student Name": "Ashy",
                    "Term1": "$1,000.00",
                    "Term2": "$1,000.00",
                    "Total": "$2,000.00",
                },
                {
                    "Student Name": "Test",
                    "Term1": "$1,000.00",
                    "Total": "$1,000.00",
                }
            ],
        }
    }
};

const allKeys = [...new Set(data.students.fees.others.flatMap(Object.keys))];
data.students.fees.others = data.students.fees.others.map((otherentry) => {
    return Object.fromEntries(allKeys.map((key) => [key, otherentry[key] || ""]));
});
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

When a missing key needed to be added, it's not necessarily in the same order as your example, but that doesn't affect the functionality or quality of data.

```js
let data = {
  "students": {
    "fees": {
      "others": [{
          "Student Name": "Ashy",
          "Term1": "$1,000.00",
          "Term2": "$1,000.00",
          "Total": "$2,000.00",
        },
        {
          "Student Name": "Test",
          "Term1": "$1,000.00",
          "Total": "$1,000.00",
        }
      ],
    }
  }
}

let keys = []
data.students.fees.others.forEach(o => {
  if (Object.keys(o).length > keys.length) keys = Object.keys(o);
})
data.students.fees.others = data.students.fees.others.map(m => {
  if (Object.keys(m).length !== keys.length) {
    keys.forEach(k => {
      if (!m.hasOwnProperty(k)) m[k] = "";
    })
  }
  return m
})

console.log(data)
```